# Form submits when page is loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

I have a problem with my form. When I click on the button, the div where I have my form is displayed, when I click on hide button, the div is hidding:

```
$(function () {
        $("#reservation").click(function () {
            $("#reservationDiv").show("slow");
        })
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#hideReservation").click(function () {
            $("#reservationDiv").hide("slow");
        })
    });
```

Then, inside my "reservationDiv" I have a form initialized in such a way:

```
@Html.BeginForm("DoReservation","OfferDetails")
```

When I however open the default "OfferDetails" controller's action (Index) my "DoReservation" action is invoked automatically. What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure if it's important but on the OfferDetails master page I also use jquery ui tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your code, you mention a button but your click handler is not suppressing the default behavior of the button. I like to use the jQuery *live()* function to bind *click* events, and you can suppressed the submit behavior of the button like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $("#reservation").live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#reservationDiv").show("slow");
        });

        $("#hideReservation").live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#reservationDiv").hide("slow");
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @tawman. I will try that later at evening and let you know